# is it necessary install solr with a servlet (Tomcat, Jetty, etc)?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, solr, installation, jetty

Is it necessary install solr with a servlets? I read several tutorials how to install solr, and most of them say that its necessary but, when I start Solr without Tomcat server works!
And I can Index xml files. I don't see the relation with Servlet Tomcat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [SolrInstall](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall) wiki page the second Requirement states

> A servlet container such as Tomcat, Jetty, or Resin

Jetty is the default (bundled) servlet. Please see the [Servlet Container or Environment Specific Tips](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Servlet_Container_or_Environment_Specific_Tips) for links to assistance with installing Solr in various Servlet Containers.

There is also the concept of [EmbeddedSolr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr), however please note the following

> The simplest, safest, way to use Solr is via Solr's standard HTTP interfaces. Embedding Solr is less flexible, harder to support, not as well tested, and should be reserved for special circumstances.

Comment: OK, It says in the  Servlet Container or Environment Specific Tips  - Jetty (default, included into Solr package) I guess, it should be in the second requirement beacuse its a bit confuse. Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know solr bundles with jetty so I suspect you are using that.

Comment: so if I just install Solr? Can I use Jetty as a servlet? or Im wrong?

Comment: jetty is a servlet container, solr has servlets that deploy into jetty, tomcat, glassfish, whatever...just saying that my understanding is that solr comes bundled with jetty in some form judging from the questions we get on the jetty side of things.  They may bundle with tomcat as well...it should be clear from their installation what they are doing though.

Comment: Yes, maybe they know but dont want to explain (or maybe not). And thanks a lot for you answer

Answer (score 0):

No, if you are using the EmbeddedSolrServer you will not need to launch solr in a web container like Tomcat.